# basic questions about SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint

I am newbie to SharePoint.  Can anyone explain when to use what?

Team Site
Blank Site
Group WorkSite
Document Workspace

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How we roll at my company:

- A blank site is a good place to start out clean and empty. Use when no other site provides any clear benefit.
- A team site is a blank site that ships with a calendar, task list, document sharing, and a few other goodies. It is good when you would plan on setting up the like anyway.
- We don't use a group work site, really.
- A document workspace is useful when collaborating on a single document, such as a contract or a proposal, if the intent is to have a heavy process for the document, including meetings, calendar events, tasks, and so on. They tend to be sub-sites in our environment.